# How can I return JSON responses with Dropwizard healthcheck?

Tags: json, health-monitoring, dropwizard

I've been working on adding healthchecks to my dropwizard service. The problem is dropwizard returns plain text responses when I run my healthchecks. And I can only add an optional string messages to this output.

For example:
* Available Disk Space: OK
Disk usage is not critically high (my message string)
* Available Memory: OK
* CPU Usage: OK
* deadlocks: OK

Is there a way to return these messages in JSON format so that I can parse the output easily?

Thanks a million!

Comment: I have the opposite problem: I only get parseable JSON, but would like a human-readable text or HTML version as well. This might have changed with recent versions, I use 0.7

Comment: I have the same issue, I want to go back to the older format which was in plain-text.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `ObjectMapper` to your healthcheck. Then you can use appropriate methods such as `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper#writeValueAsString` of ObjectMapper and pass String argument to create a healthcheck instance.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, upgrade to Dropwizard v0.7.1. The default health check format will be JSON.