# DropWizard HealthCheck Json Response

Tags: json, dropwizard, health-monitoring

I'm using dropwizard 0.6.2 for my service. The healthcheck response from dropwizard returns  plain text. And I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981107/how-can-i-return-json-responses-with-dropwizard-healthcheck) in stackoverflow which had an answer that says we can pass a ObjectMapper to a healthcheck. But I couldn't able to find a way to pass the ObjectMapper to the HealthCheck.

Is there a way to return the healthcheck response in JSON?

Answer (score 1):

As of Dropwizard **0.7**, the `/healthcheck` path returns a JSON response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Length: 299
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 14 Aug 2014 07:55:29 GMT

{
   "My custom HealthCheck":
   {
       "healthy": true,
       "message": "your message here"
   },
   "deadlocks":
   {
       "healthy": true
   },
   "storage":
   {
       "healthy": true
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how can you get JSON in 0.6?

Answer (score 0):

The Dropwizard use the codehale HealthCheck class.
You can call Result.healthy() and passing for parameter your JSON string.
In the method that you call the healthcheck you can use:

```
Result.healthy("your json");
```

Comment: @user3323968
Even after returning the json string via Result.healthy
the **/healthcheck** path in the dropwizard returns the following response
` 
* Service Health: OK
  {result:"ok"}
* Database Health: OK
  {result:"ok"}
* deadlocks: OK
`
Above response is a plain text.